# IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath parameter in TFS build

Tags: .net, deployment, tfs, msdeploy

When I go to the web project's properties, under Package/Publish tab, in Physical Path of web application on the destination server, I have set:

```
C:\Projects\TimeSheet
```

When I create a package and examine the package's zip file and look SetParameters.xml file, I see:

```
  <setParameter name="IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath" value="C:\Builds\1\TimeSheet\Web_deploy" />
```

which I think is getting from the physical location on the build server. Why is it not using what I've set in the project properties? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you make those changes on the configuration you are building? Those values are specific to the configuration that is selected in the drop-down on that page. Can you take a look and report back?

Comment: I added a new configuration called Staging and am building with that configuration. However, I don't see this listed on the Package/Publish page for me to select it and set the Physical path of the web application.

Comment: Make sure that both solution and project have that configuration defined.

Comment: I don't want to create a Staging project configuration. All I want is a Staging solution configuration (which runs all the projects in the Release mode). I know it appears that I can use a Release configuration, but since I am doing XDT based on the configuration, I created a new one.